# Cant see results from Chrome Extension to Laravel Logger

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, logging

I want to log the data from the chrome extension, but I can not get any kind of result.

SearchController.php

```
public function data(Request $request) { 
        $text = $request->all();
        Requested::insert($text);
});
```

Chrome Extension

```
$.post({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8000/search?title=kishore",
      data: {title: tabs},
                     success: function(data) {
                     console.log(data);
                     // payload :payload
                        }
     

             });
```

I have added the middleware to my route `middleware=>activity`.

But I am unable to receive any kind of data.

**Laravel version:** ***`6.18.35`***

**Db:** ***`Mysql`***

Comment: Is your function returning anything? Because it seems it does the insert, but does not return any value to be shown in data.

Comment: Did you forget to return the value of $text or any value so that your ajax would get a response ?

Comment: @Sourcerer I can see the result in the chrome console! I have used the return $text, but dint got the result in logger DB.

Comment: Your question does not say that, say the opposite. Please, edit and correct